How to enter nested form data in postman
I have my schema like i have userDetials and in userDetails i have this principal Application Detials and in i have salutation field and now i want to enter input using form data in postman how i can do that and this is my schema:
{
    "selectedOption": "Individual",
    "userDetails": {
        "principalApplicationDetails": {
            "salutation": "65fbe8ec74717b561f239821",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "fatherHusbandName": "Doe Sr.",
            "motherName": "Jane Doe",
            "identificationType": "CNIC",
            "identificationNumber": "12345-1231441-5",
            "issuanceDate": "2003-01-01",
            "expiryDate": "2022-01-01",
            "placeOfBirth": {
                "country": "65f339c5061ae53feb89c09a",
                "province": "65f5e08ca2ebc406402e3efa",
                "city": "65fd14466e03c2bef8cd98d9"
            },
            "dateOfBirth": "2003-09-19",
            "Nationality": "65f339c5061ae53feb89c09a",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "Religion": "65fb28c9a52265ff48f5fd2a",
            "zakatDeduction": "Yes",
            "nationalTaxNumber": "1234567890123",
            "taxStatus": "Filer",
            "correspondenceAddress": "123 Main St",
            "mobileNumber": "0316-4251521",
            // "post": "john.d@example.com"
            "email":"242443424342432"
        },
      
    }
}


this is my key that i am entering in form data in postman: userDetails[principalApplicationDetails][salutation] and this is my value for respective key: 65fbe8ec74717b561f239821 but it is showing me this error: userDetails.principalApplicationDetails.salutation: Path principalApplicationDetails.salutation is required."  and this is my controller code:
import userModel from "../models/userModel.js";
import fs from 'fs'
export const createUserController = async (req, res) => {
  try {

// console.log(req.fields)
      // Extract fields from the form data
      console.log(req.fields)
      const { selectedOption, userDetails} = req.fields;
      const { cnicFrontImage, cnicBackImage,salutation } = req.files;
      // const { principalApplicationDetails } = userDetails;
      // const { salutation } = principalApplicationDetails;
      // Validate the input data according to your schema
      // Handle validation errors
      // Create a new user instance based on the validated data
      const newUser = new userModel({
        selectedOption,
        userDetails: {
          ...userDetails,
          // principalApplicationDetails: {
          //   ...principalApplicationDetails,
          //   salutation: salutation // Assigning salutation directly
          // },
          cnicFrontImage: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(cnicFrontImage.path),
            contentType: cnicFrontImage.type
          },
          cnicBackImage: {
            data: fs.readFileSync(cnicBackImage.path),
            contentType: cnicBackImage.type
          }
        }
      });

      // Save the new user instance to the database
      await newUser.save();

      // Send success response
      return res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'New user created successfully',
        user: newUser
      });
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating user:', error);
    
    // Handle errors and send appropriate response
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: 'Error creating user',
      error: error.message
    });
  }
};


Why not JSON/raw? This should better support nested structures as form data as a content type typically does not
